# illegal start of expression java public static void

Tags: java

I am very new to Java but have come across the following error, and can't for the life of me figure out why... At the public static void line I'm getting illegal start of expression.

```
public int inputAge()
{
    int age=0;
    boolean  inputValid = true;
    public static void inputAge()
        {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Age: ");
        age = console.nextint();
        
        if (age < 18) 
            {
            inputValid = false;
            System.out.print("too young");
            break;
            }
        else if (age >= 18)
            {
            continue;
            }        
        }
```

Comment: Because you’re declaring  a method inside another method.

Answer (score 1):

It's because Java doesn't allow nested methods. You have defined a method InputAge inside another method named InputAge. You also cannot have two methods with the same name and definition in the same class. You will have to separate the two methods and rename them so they have unique names, or just merge them into one.

Your method should look something like this:

```
public int inputAge()
{
    int age=0;
    boolean  inputValid = true;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Age: ");
    age = console.nextint();
    
    if (age < 18) 
        {
        inputValid = false;
        System.out.print("too young");
        break;
        }
    else if (age >= 18)
        {
        continue;
        }        
    }
    //make sure you return an int value
    return age;
}
```